# Should I use list() or [] when defining a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever I come to define an empty list. Which is best practice? Is one better than the other? Are they identical?

```
mylist = list()
```

or?

```
mylist = []
```

My question is also relevant to:

```
# int() && 0
# str() && ""
# float() && 0.0
# etc.
```

But just in case there's a difference. I am only interested in the answer for lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I actually ran that again, and `[]` turned out to be faster. Added the new scores.

I prefer `mylist=[]` for readability, but `mylist = list()` also works. In terms of performance:

```py
>>> python -m timeit 'mylist=[]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0229 usec per loop
```

```py
>>> python -m timeit 'mylist=list()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.105 usec per loop
```

Comment: `list()` is probably a bit slower in real life. In your timing, the compiler might have the benefit of noting that `list` could not have been assigned any other value, and so optimized to `mylist = []`. In real life, the compiler would likely have to perform the global name lookup and call the type, rather than simply assume that `list() == []`.

Comment: @chepner pretty sure that isn't happening. There is no way for the compiler to know that, for example, calling `list` could modify `list`!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga With a very small, constrained source, it can. Compare `python -m timeit -s 'listb = list' 'mylist = listb()'` with `python -m timeit -s 'listb = list' 'mylist = []'`; in my tests, the former is 3 times slower.

Comment: (I suspect that if the peephole optimizer sees that `list` is bound in the built-in scope, it can determine it is safe to replace `list()` with `[]`.)

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure what you think that demonstrates. In any case, I am pretty sure there is no such optimization done by the Python compiler, the peephole optimizer is limited to pretty basic things.

Comment: @chepner so note, `python -m timeit -s 'listb = list' 'mylist = list()` is slower than `python -m timeit -s 'listb = list' 'mylist = listb()` which is slower than `python -m timeit -s 'listb = list' 'mylist = []`, which is exactly what we would expect if the interpreter were simply acting stupidly, but optimizing the building of the literal by supporting it at the byte-code level

Comment: Since I claim that Python optimizes away the name lookup in `mylist = list()` alone, my point was to generate a test that forces a name lookup.

Comment: @chepner well, you can use `dis` to see that the compiler is definitely not doing this. If the peep-hole optimizer were able to figure this out, you'd see the same bytecode generated for `mylist=list()` and `mylist = []`. And you do not.

Comment: I don't think `dis` is doing the same optimization, since it's not actually running anything.

Comment: @chepner dude, dis is telling you *exactly* what the interpreter sees *before* it runs anything, and the bytecode is what gets executed. There is no other opportunity for it to optimize anything at that point, what's in the bytecode is what gets executed. Of course, this is about CPython, a JITed python implementation would be another story.

Comment: So, just like Péter, I reran the test, and likewise do not see `[]` and `list()` taking the same amount of time now. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.